# Can I define an object as equal to another one in Java?

Tags: java

In Java programs, is it right to set an object equal to another one? To be more specific, I'm studying binary trees and I noticed in the following code:

```
public Node find(int key)
{
    Node current = root;
    while(current.iData != key) 
    {
        if(key < current.iData)
        {
            current = current.leftChild;
        } else {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

that both `Node current = root;` and  `current - current.leftChild;` are setting an object equal to another one. Is this right?

Comment: That's not what it's doing, no. You're setting current to different instances.

Comment: read and understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740042/6194785

Answer (score 2):

> *setting an object equal to another one. Is this right?*

No, that's not right.

---

What's actually happening is, you're changing the reference of one variable to another object.

So:

```
Node current = root; // "current" will point at the same object as `root`.
```

and

```
current = current.leftChild; // "current" will point at the same object as `leftChild`.
```

note -

When assigning primitive types with `=` is a completely different behaviour when assigning reference types with `=`.

Comment: Good answer, I just want to add that for further reading the OP can find more details in the [Java Tutorial on Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to need a basic concept in Java: **Java does manipulate objects by reference, and all object variables are references**.

So when you have `Object o1` and `Object o2`, in fact o1 and o2 are just references to memory spaces that hold the object **not the object itself**.

When you have o1 == o2 , you are comparing the two references not the objects themselves but if you want to compare them you need to override the `equals()` method.

Now, let's talk about your case:

`Node current = root;` this means that current and root are referring to the same object (the same location in memory). **So there is only one object and two references**.